# Show JavaScript associative array in html table using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

I need to print out the results of a sort on an associative array in JavaScript in a HTML table not using PHP or those things.
The sorting works fine as I can see that in the console but it doesn't show the table. Here is the source as far as I have it now:

```js
var array = [{
  name: 'TK345',
  year: 2011,
  custom: 456,
  colour: 'red'
}, {

  name: 'ZJ456',
  year: 2001,
  custom: 96,
  colour: 'black'
}, {
  name: 'AW364',
  year: 1985,
  custom: 001,
  colour: 'cyan'
}, {
  name: 'RT112',
  year: 2012,
  custom: 33,
  colour: 'green'
}, {
  name: 'PO445',
  year: 2012,
  custom: 11,
  colour: 'yellow'
}];

function sortarray(sorter) {

  if (array.length < 1) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (sorter == "name") {

    var byName = array.slice(0);
    var tableout = document.createElement('table');
    var retval = null;
    byName.sort(function(a, b) {

      var x = a.name.toLowerCase();
      var y = b.name.toLowerCase();
      retval = x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0;

      tableout.setAttribute('border', '1');
      tableout.setAttribute('width', '100%')
      var row = tableout.insertRow(0);
      for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
        row = tableout.insertRow(j - 1);
        for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
          var text = document.createTextNode(retval);
        var cell = row.insertCell(i - 1);
        cell.setAttribute('align', 'center')
        cell.appendChild(text);
      }
    })
    document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(tableout);
    console.log(retval );

  } else if (sorter == "year") {

    var byDate = array.slice(0);
    var tableout = document.createElement('table');
    var retval = null;
    byDate.sort(function(a, b) {

      retval = a.year - b.year;

      tableout.setAttribute('border', '1');
      tableout.setAttribute('width', '100%')
      var row = tableout.insertRow(0);
      for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
        row = tableout.insertRow(j - 1);
        for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
          var text = document.createTextNode(retval );
        var cell = row.insertCell(i - 1);
        cell.setAttribute('align', 'center')
        cell.appendChild(text);
      }
    })
    document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(tableout);
    console.log(retval );

  } else {};

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button onclick="sortarray('name')">Sort by Name</button>
  <button onclick="sortarray('year')">Sort by Year</button>
  <p id="demo">test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

So it doesn't show me anything of that table on the page or in the console.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have return statement above all these table creating stuff.

Comment: Thought to return that, now I have it in a variable.... updating source in question .. sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is broken in so many ways:

- You have returns in wrong places
- You do not need two different functions, you just need to have a different sort function
- Doing something like `for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)` and then use `i-1` is bad. Start counting from 0
- You cannot access to Object using integer, you need to use its keys (see my inner for)
- You do not need `else {}`
- Be careful with indentation, it highlights logic errors as well.
- You do not need to print the table **inside** the sort function

I removed some of your errors, this function works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="sortarray('name')">Sort by Name</button>
<button onclick="sortarray('year')">Sort by Year</button>
<p id="demo">test</p>

<script>
var array = [   
 {
    name: 'TK345',
    year: 2011,
    custom: 456,
    colour: 'red'
 },
 {

    name: 'ZJ456',
    year: 2001,
    custom: 96,
    colour: 'black'
},
{            
    name: 'AW364',
    year: 1985,
    custom: 001,
    colour: 'cyan'
},    
{
    name: 'RT112',
    year: 2012,
    custom: 33,
    colour: 'green'
},
{
    name: 'PO445',
    year: 2012,
    custom: 11,
    colour: 'yellow'
   }
];

function sortarray(sorter) {
  if (array.length < 1) {return -1;}

  var elems = array.slice(0);
  elems.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (sorter === 'name') {
      var x = a.name.toLowerCase();
      var y = b.name.toLowerCase();
      return x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0;
    }

    return a.year - b.year;
  });
  
  var tableout = document.createElement('table');
  tableout.setAttribute('border','1');
  tableout.setAttribute('width','100%');
  
  var row = tableout.insertRow(0);
    
  for (var j=0; j<5; j++) {
    row = tableout.insertRow(j);
    var keys = Object.keys(elems[j]);
    for (var i=0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      var text = document.createTextNode(elems[j][keys[i]]);
      var cell = row.insertCell(i);
      cell.setAttribute('align','center');
      cell.appendChild(text);
    }
  }
  
  document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(tableout);
  console.log(elems);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow thanks.... I will have a look at this source.... I kow mine was pretty messed up, sorry for that.. well only experience makes you become better. So thanks for your help.

Comment: @Thevagabond sure thing, and this is way I tried to highlight your errors, so next time it will be better :) Anyway, take a look to 'Learning Javascript'  here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, will do so.

Answer (score 0):

We do this job with a generic `tableMaker` function. So the below code will generate a table for you. The generic tableMaker function takes an array of an object or an array of multiple objects provided in the first argument. All objects should have same keys (properties) since these keys are used to create the table header (if the second argument is set to true) and the values are used to create each row. It will return an HTML table text.

Besides i have added a very simple sorting functionality which sorts the rows according to the column data when you click the corresponding header. As of now it won't do ascending descending switch but give the idea on how to approach.

```js
function tableMaker(o,h){
  var keys = Object.keys(o[0]),
  rowMaker = (a,t) => a.reduce((p,c,i,a) => p + (i === a.length-1 ? "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + "></tr>"
                                                                  : "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + ">"),"<tr>"),
      rows = o.reduce((r,c) => r + rowMaker(keys.reduce((v,k) => v.concat(c[k]),[]),"td"),h ? rowMaker(keys,"th") : []);
  return "<table>" + rows + "</table>";
}

function sorter(e){
  tableData.sort((a,b) => a[e.currentTarget.textContent] < b[e.currentTarget.textContent] ? -1 : 1);
  myTable.innerHTML = tableMaker(tableData,true);
  thList = myTable.querySelectorAll("table tr th");
  for (var th of thList) {
    th.addEventListener("click", sorter);
    th.textContent === e.currentTarget.textContent ? th.classList = "selected_header"
                                                   : th.classList = "header";
  }
}

var tableData = [{name: 'TK345', year: 2011, custom: 456, colour: 'red'},
                 {name: 'ZJ456', year: 2001, custom: 96, colour: 'black'},
                 {name: 'AW364', year: 1985, custom: 001, colour: 'cyan'},
                 {name: 'RT112', year: 2012, custom: 33, colour: 'green'},
                 {name: 'PO445', year: 2012, custom: 11, colour: 'yellow'}],
      myTable = document.getElementById("myTable"),
       thList;

myTable.innerHTML = tableMaker(tableData,true);
thList = myTable.querySelectorAll("table tr th");
  for (var th of thList) {
    th.addEventListener("click", sorter);
    th.classList = "header";
  }
```

```css
.header {
        border: 2px solid tomato;
 border-radius: 6px;
    background: pink;
}

.selected_header {
        border: 2px solid turquoise;
 border-radius: 6px;
    background: paleGreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="myTable"></div>
```